# Pronouns referring and antecedents structure confusing

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, adverbial-phrases, personal-pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

> Someone moved paper from a space meant for the storage of shared materials and intended to store them in a room they are solely using.

I’m not sure how to fix the combination of the content for the nouns and pronouns that refer. Is it dangling?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking for help improving the phrasing? We don't do that on this site. It's question-and-answer only here

Comment: The sentence makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what the sentence seems to be intended to mean, but it is confusing and awkwardly worded. Specifically:

- The word "*paper*" here is a singualr foirm. "Paper" is a mass noun. so this would mean a quantity or stack of paper, or perhaps a box of paper. it does not agree with the pronoun "*them*" al;thogh "paper" is the antecedent of "them". The pronoun "it" should be used instead of "them".
- The verb "*intended*" is a past-tense form, but the sentence is discussing an intention that apparently never was carried out. A future form such as "from a space meant for the storage of shared materials, intending to store it..."
- The word "*solely*" is accurate here, but I think it feels rather awkward. This could be rewritten to use a word such as "*alone*" or "*separatly*".